# SpringMVC HTTP Status 404 -

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm starting to learn **Spring MVC**, but when I run my program, I am getting the following error:

> HTTP Status 404 -
>   type Status report
>   message
>   description The requested resource is not available.
>   Apache Tomcat/8.0.41

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**springmvc-servlet.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

     <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
     <mvc:annotation-driven/>
     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
         <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
         <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
     </bean>
</beans>
```

**SpringTest.java**:

```
package com;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class SpringTest {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home",method =RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

My **project structure** is as follows:

[image]

I use IntelliJ IDEA to run this procedure. Will the IntelliJ IDEA be the reason for the error I'm getting?

Comment: It doesn't fail when you run the program. It fails when you send an HTTP request. What HTTP request did you send?

Comment: I use Tomcat to test.So,I don't know HTTP request  to my send

Answer (score 1):

Please to change the order between `<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>` and `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` make `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` the first

You are trying to access `${ContextPath}/home/home`, please try to replace your controller by below code:

```
@Controller
public class SpringTest {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home",method =RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but after I tried it or not.I'm going crazy